# Determining number of warps allowed in CUDA SM

Tags: cuda

So if a streaming multiprocessor can allow maximum X threads, while each block in the SM allows Y threads, how many warps can we have in a block and how many warps can we have in a SM?

Here is my take on this question:

(1) A warp consists of 32 threads. In a block we can have Y/32, right?

(2) As far as # of warps per SM, we cannot exceed X the maximum number of threads in SM, so we can have X/32, right? I hope somebody can confirm these calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Yes, rounding up if needed (i.e. if number of threads Y per block is not evenly divisible by 32)

(2) Yes, that is one limit on the number of warps that may be active.  Remember that the SM scheduler works by scheduling blocks *first*.  The number of blocks that will be scheduled is a function of available resources (registers, shared memory, threads, etc.)  A block will only be scheduled when there are enough resources available to support it's needs.  So for example, if I have 1024 threads per block, I can schedule at most 1 block on an SM, because the limit of 1536 threads per SM (using CC 2.0 as an example here) prevents 2 blocks from being scheduled.  So in that case, even though your X/32 number predicts a max of 48 warps, only 1024/32 = 32 warps will be scheduled. (using CC 2.0 as an example, with a block structure of 1024 threads per block).

Comment: To be clear: This means the limit of (e.g. 64) warps per SM is implied by the limit of (e.g. 2048) threads per SM and isn't a separate limit that must be taken into account separately?

Comment: I am asking because Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) has a table with a separate row for "Maximum number of resident warps per multiprocessor" that looks like a separate limit but is always proportional to "Maximum number of resident threads per multiprocessor". That is confusing.

Comment: Yes, the limit of 64 warps per SM is implied by the limit of 2048 threads per SM.  I think that covers most sensible discussion of it.  To think about oddball cases, if you had 65 threads per block, someone might naively think that the threads per SM limit would imply a maximum of 31 blocks per SM, but in actuality those threadblocks of 65 threads consist of 3 warps each, so the maximum would be 21 threadblocks, considering only those two limits.